# Wordpress /category/subcategory 404 error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am new at WordPress and I would like to create a url structure for a recipe site.

/category ( eg: /recipe will list all recipes ).

/category/subcategory ( eg: recipe/chicken list of chicken recipes )

/category/subcategory/postname ( eg: recipe/chicken/Chicken-Breasts-with-Tomatoes

The problem:

When I access /category/subcategory ( /recipe/chicken ) i got 404 not found, but if i access /subcategory ( eg: /chicken ) it works.

I had marked the category "recipe" as the parent of chicken.

Tks a lot,
enog

Comment: I'm assuming you created this via taxonomy and it's not the built in posts? It may be useful to post that code, otherwise try re-saving your permalink structure in the admin panel.

Comment: Try resaving the permalink settings so that you'll flush the permalink cache. Also make sure your permalink settings are indeed correct to identify subcategories beneath categories.

Comment: my permalinks: /%category%/%postname%/ . How can i configure wordpress to identify subcategories beneath categories?

Answer (score 2):

You can change your permalinks, adding some extension at the end:

```
/%category%/%postname%.html
```

I don't like this solution much, but it makes subcategory pages work.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that work for me was /%category%/%subcategory%/%postname%/ but it a little bit messy with the new posts that you create.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting 'en' (short for English) as base for category. This kept the beauty of URL as well as do the job for me that I wanted. It also impacted SEO as search engine thinks of 'en' as 'English'.

Answer (score 0):

/%category%/%subcategory%/%postname%/   works like a dream to see the excertps of the posts on the subcategory page!!!
however it messes up the links to the posts
if you change the wp-admin/options-permalink.php  to just postname then it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can try using SEO tools for wordpress such as **Yoast** or **Rank Math**.

These Seo tools offer a way for you to **remove/strip** the category base of your permalink structure.

Just make sure to remove your first approach which was adding a dot(.) on the category base in the permalink page.